# child is not executing after fork()-ing

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork, runtime-error

```
int status=0;
int PID = fork();
if(PID == 0)
{
   char *path = strcat(pathToken,strcat("/",command));
   printf("path: %s\n",path);
   execl(path,command,"-l",NULL);
}
else if(PID>0)
{
   printf("pid: %d. ",PID);
   printf("I'm parent process\n");
   wait(&status);
}
```

Output:

```
pid: 20027. I'm parent process
```

Why it doesn't enter `if(PID==0)`?

Comment: Most probably the child starts, but crashes immediately when trying to execute `strcat("/",command)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to modify a string literal in:

```
strcat("/",command)
```

which leads to undefined behavior.

The declaration for strcat is:

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

And it appends a copy of the source string to the destination string.

Comment: And this would have been caught by the compiler, if you passed it the `-Wall` flag, you'll have a warning....

Answer (score 2):

> Q: Why doesn't it enter "if pid == 0")?

A: It probably does :)

Two suggestions:

1) step through under the debugger and see what "path" is before you call "execl()".  I think you'll be surprised.

2) Be sure to check the error status of "execl()" in your code.  Never assume that it won't fail, and be sure to print a meaningful error message (and/or recover gracefully) if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
char *path = strcat(pathToken,strcat("/",command));
```

to

```
char * path = malloc(strlen(pathtoken) +
                     strlen(command) + 2); /* 1 for null + one for / */
strcpy(path, pathToken);
strcat(path, "/");
strcat(path, command);
```

Me thinks that should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked strcat, thought ill figure it out later, as long as im inside "if(pid==0)". I thought it should give error at least

Comment: @nzrksafina - An aside - treat writing a computer program as baking a cake. Take once step at a time. Trying to do two things at once you either have a burnt cake or the cooker explodes!